# Error when trying to run a git project

Tags: .net, node.js, coffeescript

I am trying to run this project on my Windows 7: 
https://github.com/JoelBesada/pasteboard#readme

I followed the instructions on the project-page but it won't run.
When I execute in my console

`./run_local`

I get the message that run_local can't be found (but I am in project-folder).

I have node.js installed as well as coffeescript.js and app.js.

While performing "npm install" I get an error after a while.

Do I need a .NET-framework?  Why can't I run the project?

Comment: there's no such thing like a **git Project**. Git is used for tracking the changes in the project, but it has nothing to do with the project itself...

Comment: **Which** error do you get when executing `npm install`???

Comment: I get this error: http://imgur.com/Yct5BO7

Comment: i dont know much about node on windows, but you probably should use cygwin: http://www.cygwin.com/. i dont think working on the windows shell would work...

Comment: @hereandnow78 alot of node modules have build steps for windows, and cygwin is NOT recomented whith node anymore (since node 0.4 i think)

Comment: so then i was wrong, just ignore my comment